# Use ReaderT Maybe or MaybeT Reader?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I want to write a haskell program reading config and do something. The config is a `Data.Map` and will be injected into a Reader. And when we can't find a config item, the reading should be interrupted. Just stopped, no error messages are required. So I just want a Maybe monad(not Either monad).

The problem is, how should I stack the two monads, `ReaderT Maybe` or `MaybeT Reader`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I figure it out. Both of them are OK.

Assume every config item's value is just an Int.

The `ReaderT ConfigMap Maybe Int` will have a value like:

```
ReaderT (\r -> Just 123)
```

or

```
ReaderT (\r -> Nothing)
```

The `MaybeT (Reader ConfigMap) Int` will have a value like:

```
MaybeT (Reader (\r -> Just 123))
```

or:

```
MaybeT (Reader (\r -> Nothing))
```

With either, we can first do some read, then decide whether we should continue according whether the read returns a `Nothing`. The values have different outer shapes but the same functionality.

My little demo here:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

type Config = M.Map String Int

getConfig :: String -> MaybeT (Reader Config) Int
getConfig key = MaybeT $ do
  m <- ask
  return $ M.lookup key m

readAll :: Config -> Maybe (Int, Int)
readAll m =
  let r = runMaybeT $ do
      a <- getConfig "a"
      b <- getConfig "b"
      return (a, b)
  in runReader r m

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ show (readAll $ M.fromList [("x", 3), ("b", 4)])
```

My second demo:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

type Config = M.Map String Int

getConfig :: String -> ReaderT Config Maybe Int
getConfig key = ReaderT $ \r -> M.lookup key r

readAll :: Config -> Maybe (Int, Int)
readAll m =
  let r = runReaderT $ do
      a <- getConfig "a"
      b <- getConfig "b"
      return (a, b)
  in r m

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ show (readAll $ M.fromList [("a", 3), ("b", 4)])
```

Comment: If you expand the types without the `newtype` constructors, you find they both unroll to `r -> Maybe a`, which is a good hint that they might be the same.  But there are some cases where the monad operators will have different behavior even though they have the same type, e.g. `ListT (State s)` vs `StateT s []`.  (This is because `ListT` is kind of broken... but that makes it a good example in cases like this!)

Comment: I found that `ReaderT Maybe` and `MaybeT Reader` is really a special pair. And what make a pair like this is the same "inner shape" (the remain things after geting rid of all type constructors and lambdas(`\a ->`) of a monad value). By the way, for a logged computation which may fails, `MaybeT Writer` and `WriterT Maybe` are different: the former will fails with `(Nothing, "first N lines of log")`, while the latter with only `Nothing`.